# return redirect_to in private controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Preface:  I'm using devise for authentication.

I'm trying to catch unauthorized users from being able to see, edit, or update another user's information.  My biggest concern is a user modifying the form in the DOM to another user's ID, filling out the form, and clicking update.  I've read specifically on SO that something like below should work, but it doesn't.  A post on SO recommended moving the `validate_current_user` method into the public realm, but that didn't work either.

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?  Or is there a better approach to what I'm trying to do, either using devise or something else?

My `UsersController` looks like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin!, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy]
  before_filter :redirect_guests

  def index
    redirect_to current_user unless current_user.try(:admin?)

    if params[:approved] == "false"
      @users = User.find_all_by_approved(false)
    else
      @users = User.all
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    validate_current_user
    @user
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    validate_current_user
    @user
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, :notice => 'User was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    validate_current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, :notice => 'User was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def redirect_guests
    redirect_to new_user_session_path if current_user.nil?
  end

  def validate_current_user
    if current_user && current_user != @user && !current_user.try(:admin?)
      return redirect_to(current_user)
    end
  end

end
```

The `authenticate_admin!` method looks like this:

```
  def authenticate_admin!
    return redirect_to new_user_session_path if current_user.nil?

    unless current_user.try(:admin?)
      flash[:error] = "Unauthorized access!"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
```

**EDIT**  --  **What do you mean "it doesn't work?"**

To help clarify, I get this error when I try to "hack" another user's account:

> Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action.
>   Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most
>   once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate
>   execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after
>   redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and
>   return".

If I put the method code inline in the individual controller actions, they *do* work.  But, I don't want to do that because it isn't DRY.

I should also specify I've tried:

```
def validate_current_user
  if current_user && current_user != @user && !current_user.try(:admin?)
     redirect_to(current_user) and return
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you specify specific errors instead of "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Yes, I can, and I should have.  One shouldn't code and deal with a toddler. ;-)  See the edit coming above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying and you want to authorize users before every action. I would suggest you to use standard gems like CanCan or declarative_authorization.

Going ahead with this approach you might end up reinventing the wheel.

In case you decide on using cancan, all you have to do is add permissions in the ability.rb file(generated by rails cancan:install)

can [:read,:write,:destroy], :role => "admin"

And in the controller just add load_and_authorize_resource (cancan filter). It will check if the user has permissions for the current action. If the user doesnt have persmissions, then it will throw a 403 forbidden expection, which can be caught in the ApplicationController and handled appropriately.

Comment: This will help with the user editing the DOM's form to another user ID?

Comment: Additionally, I think CanCan is too heavy for what I need.  I think the authorization that comes with devise will do for what I need.

Comment: If this is the only place in your app that needs authorization, then it might make sense to not use cancan. But if there are going to be other actions in other controllers which will require authorization, then it is better to implement it with cancan or any other authorization gem.

Comment: This is a good point. I will have other authorization areas other than users, so I may end up using CanCan.  But I'm not convinced CanCan will solve my main problem.

Comment: I am now convinced CanCan will solve my main problem.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: This is just a workaround, can you provide a solution to the answer. How can you redirect_to from a private method?

Answer (score 4):

If you think about it, `return` in the private method just exits the method and passes control back to the controller - it doesn't quit the action.  If you want to quit the action you have to return again

For example, you could have something like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    return if redirect_guest_posts(params[:guest], params[:id])
    ...
  end

  private

  def redirect_guest_post(author_is_guest, post_id)
    redirect_to special_guest_post_path(post_id) if author_is_guest
  end
end
```

If params[:guest] is present and not false, the private method returns something truthy and the #show action quits.  If the condition fails then it returns nil, and the action continues.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
before_filter :redirect_guests, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

should work.

This is because you are using redirect twice, in authenticate_admin! and redirect_guests for new, create and destroy actions.

Comment: Nope - no dice.  When I login as user with id = 2, and go to the `/users/2/edit` path, I can still edit the dom with:

`<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/5" class="edit_user" id="edit_user_2" method="post">`

When I then submit the form, I get:

`AbstractController::DoubleRenderError at /users/5 -- Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action....`

Comment: write a **return** after redirect_to root_path in authenticate_admin!

Comment: Added, but didn't help when, as user id 2, going to /users/2/edit, manipulating the DOM to have the form post to /users/5, changing data, and clicking submit.  I still get the `AbstractController::DoubleRenderError at /users/5` error.

Answer (score 0):

"Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action."

That's the reason of the error. In `show` method, if you are neither the owner of this account nor the admin, you are facing two actions: `redirect_to` and `render`

My suggestion is to put all of the redirect logic into `before_filter`

Comment: Do you mean the `update` method?  The `show` method works as advertised.

Comment: Hard to figure out, sorry.

Comment: No worries. The biggest problem I have right now is the update method.