# Rails 3 - Prevent form_for DOM action change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

To generalize [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990326/return-redirect-to-in-private-controller-method) I asked this morning, and please accept my apologies if this has been asked before and I simply don't know what to search for, but I'm curious how Rails handles the following situation:

1. Using Devise, I log in a user, with an ID of 2.
2. I click on a link that has been created to "edit my profile" (which simply would go to the /users/2/edit page).
3. Using Firebug (or something similar), I modify the form and change the action from `action='/users/2'` to `action='/users/5'`.
4. I change an element on the form, and click submit.

At this point, Rails appears to allow the submission and update user with ID 5 with my changes.

I'm guessing I'm not the first one to ask this question.  It seems to me like Rails should handle this "out of the box", but I could be wrong.  Does Rails handle this natively and I'm just missing something?  Has this been asked before on SO or somewhere else that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things:

- Don't create a route that accepts a DB `id`. Instead, make it something like `/my_profile`.
- If an `id` is passed in the params, ignore it entirely in the controller. Instead lookup the `current_user` that is logged in and show them their own profile regardless of what profile/user `id` is passed in.
- Finally, and possibly most important, use authorization (what a user is allowed to do) in order to **disallow** one user from editing another user's profile. Not to be confused with **authentication** (user logins/logouts).

With this approach it won't matter if the DOM is changed, because the server should never implicitly trust what is passed to it, which is the problem you're facing now. Any web/app server must always confirm that the parameters being passed to it are actually valid in the context of what the current user is allowed to do.

This idea that the server should **never** trust what's passed to it is a critical idea to apply to every single action in your app, without exception.